# Apply a comparable value type Int to an UIImage object in Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object, uiimage

I'm making a simple matching game and in the matching game the user will click a button when the picture of an animal matches the word that represents the animal's name. Both the picture and the word are UIImages in my app. I figured out how to compare two image objects in an array in order to determine if they match and apply the score, accordingly ...

```
if gameMode == 1 {

        if animalWord.image == animalPic.image {

            scoreInt += 1
            scoreLabel.text = String("Score: \(scoreInt)")

        } else {

            scoreInt -= 1
            scoreLabel.text = String("Score: \(scoreInt)")

        }

    }
```

However, this will not accomplish what I need it to do because the UIImages will not be identical. Thus, I need to assign each UIImage a value that can be the same and compare those values. In other words, if I can assign a value of 1 to a UIImage of a picture of a pig and also assign the value of 1 to a UIImage of the word PIG, then I should be able to compare those values to see if they match. This should be possible, I just can't figure out how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a struct and add a custom equality operator

```
struct Item : Equatable {
    let image : UIImage
    let value : Int

    static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}
```

Then create instances of `Item` assigning the images and the appropriate values

```
let item1 = Item(image : UIImage(named: "PigAnimal")!, value: 1)
let item2 = Item(image : UIImage(named: "PigWord")!, value: 1)
```

and compare

```
if gameMode == 1 {

    if item1 == item2 {
        scoreInt += 1                
    } else {
        scoreInt -= 1             
    }
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(scoreInt)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You taught me something new. I do have two questions that I hope your kind enough to briefly answer. 1) Using the MVC pattern, should this struct be placed in a "Model" file outside of the "View Controller" file? 2) What does "lhs" and "rhs" stand for?

Comment: 1) Yes, it's good practice. 2) It's taken from the sample code in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable). I think it means *l*eft and *r*ight *h*and *s*ide

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate the follow up.